# Creating column based on conditions for data tables on R

Tags: r, datatable, tidyr

I'm trying to create a round column for my data table on R. It should be grouped by identifier.

The conditions are like this:

- each round is completed when the both options are seen (A, B)
- when a round is completed, the round number increases by 1.

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

My problem is that when I create the column, I always have to wrong round number for the observation that are the end of round. eg: observation 3 is round = 2 instead of round = 1

Comment: I can't tell from your output above, but is it a function from starting to count at 1 instead of 0.  If so, you should get the right answer by just subtracting 1 from your `round` variable.

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid using words such as "urgent" when asking a question - see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/12567365)

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? So, as well as describing your code, you can show us your code - but just the minimal code (and data) needed to allow us to recreate your issue easily. That will help us to avoid guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you have outlined in your example. I changed the variable "round" to "round_" as `round()` is an R function:

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(identifier = rep(c("122-1-1", 
                                    "123-4-5", 
                                    "234-5-6"),
                                  each = 4),
                 trial = rep(1:4, 3),
                 option = c("A", "A", "B", "A", 
                            "A", "B", "B", "A", 
                            "A", "A", "A", "A"))

df %>%
  group_by(identifier) %>%
  mutate(round_ = ifelse("A" %in% option &
                           "B" %in% option &
                           trial == max(trial), 2, 1)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 × 4
 identifier  trial option  round_
      <chr>  <int>  <chr>   <dbl>
1   122-1-1      1      A       1
2   122-1-1      2      A       1
3   122-1-1      3      B       1
4   122-1-1      4      A       2
5   123-4-5      1      A       1
6   123-4-5      2      B       1
7   123-4-5      3      B       1
8   123-4-5      4      A       2
9   234-5-6      1      A       1
10  234-5-6      2      A       1
11  234-5-6      3      A       1
12  234-5-6      4      A       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution from [top answer of this post with a minor change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388125/assign-id-to-consecutive-groups-column-r) (credit to @Leroy Tyrone for the data):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(identifier = rep(c("122-1-1", 
                                    "123-4-5", 
                                    "234-5-6"),
                                  each = 4),
                 trial = rep(1:4, 3),
                 option = c("A", "A", "B", "A", 
                            "A", "B", "B", "A", 
                            "A", "A", "A", "A"),stringsAsFactors = F)


df%>%
  mutate(round=with(rle(option), rep(ave(lengths, values, FUN = seq_along), lengths)),.by=identifier)

   identifier trial option round
1     122-1-1     1      A     1
2     122-1-1     2      A     1
3     122-1-1     3      B     1
4     122-1-1     4      A     2
5     123-4-5     1      A     1
6     123-4-5     2      B     1
7     123-4-5     3      B     1
8     123-4-5     4      A     2
9     234-5-6     1      A     1
10    234-5-6     2      A     1
11    234-5-6     3      A     1
12    234-5-6     4      A     1
```